# How to push subdocument into an array using MongoDB

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
I the user document I got an item called following which is an array.
I need to push a subdocument containing a users fullname and ID into this array.

Everytime I try the subdocument end up being a subarray.

I am using Alex Bilbie's MongoDB library and this is my query:

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array('_id'=>$user_id))->push('following', array("{id: 'aa', fullname: 'James Bond'}"))->update('users');
```

I need the results to be like this:

```
following : [
    { fullname : "James", id : aa},
    { fullname : "Jane", id : bb}
  ]
```

**Update:**

I solved it this way:

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array('_id'=>$user_id))->push('following', array('fullname'=>'Earl Spencer','id'=>'bb'))->update('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String fullname = "James";
  String id = "aa"
  var myResult = this.mongo_collections_Users.FindAndModify(

  Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(id_as_string))),
  SortBy.Ascending("_id"),
  Update.PushWrapped<item_following>("following", new item_following(fullname, id) )),
  true
  );
```

This code will find the Document into collections "Users" witch have specific _id.
  After that will "push" (add) a new item into the array "following".

If you want to store an reference to User, instead of a new "item_following" please
  use "MongoDbRef".

Hope that i can have help you,